# Dealing with a JSON Response in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Using PHP, I have decoded this JSON Response..

```
Array ( [Request] => Array ( [RequestGuid] => 4ca35135-2560-42ef-bd63-6b22cbf369ed [PackageId] => c1bf0061-b0b7-4f71-8a9a-43d6e468e5ec [PackageVersion] => 2 [ResponseVersion] => 2 [DataKeys] => Array ( [Vrm] => KM14AKK ) ) [Response] => Array ( [StatusCode] => Success [StatusMessage] => Success [StatusInformation] => Array ( [Lookup] => Array ( [StatusCode] => Success [StatusMessage] => Success [AdviceTextList] => Array ( ) ) )
```

When I run...

```
  $data = json_decode($response, true);
  for ($i=0;$i<count($jsonArray);$i++){
    echo $jsonArray[$i];
  }
```

I get the error...

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0
```

Any quick pointers as to how to access data in this feed, arrays always blag my head, I can see there is no key in this one?

Thanks.

Comment: use `foreach($data as $value)`

Comment: Use foreach loop as foreach($data as $d){ print_r($d); }

Comment: From the output you can see the keys in [] - so `"Request"` (from `[Request]`) etc.

Comment: using forrach ($data as $d) { print_r($d); } worked ! How can I now access individual names and values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `foreach` loop instead of `for` loop so change loop as:

```
$data = json_decode($response, true);
  for ($i=0;$i<count($jsonArray);$i++){
    echo $jsonArray[$i];
  }
```

To:

```
$data = json_decode($response, true);
foreach($data as $d){
   print_r($d); 
}
```

Here your `$response` JSON data does not have index value. It has `keys and values` pair. So you can not use index here.

Comment: This worked, how would I then target a specific key to get a value?

Comment: pleae ptrin_r($d) and you will data array in key and value pairs try as $d['RequestGuid'] etc.

Comment: When i do echo $d['RequestGuid'] I get... Notice: Undefined index: RequestGuid

Answer (score 0):

You should notice,The array does not have a 0 index, second, it is a multidimensional array, you can not echo its element.

Try

```
 $data = json_decode($response);
  foreach ($data as $da){
    var_dump($da);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$data = json_decode($response, true);
for ($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++){
    echo $data[$i];
}
```

Comment: Still returns Notice: Undefined offset: 0

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = json_decode($response, true);
  for ($i=0;$i<count($jsonArray);$i++){
    echo $jsonArray[$i];
  }
```

In your code, $jsonArray - defined no where.

Comment: Still returns Notice: Undefined offset: 0